# How to make a custom Edittext,so that it will look like as 45 degree rotated in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget

How to make a custom Edittext,so that it will look like as 45 degree rotated in android and it should editable so that th euser can enter text on that rotated Edittext.I tried it.But I am not getting any solution for it.Please give some idea to do this.

Comment: On API Level 11+, use [`setRotation()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setRotation(float)) on a regular `EditText`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a different way and it is working.

```
EditText lEditTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Edit_ID);
        Animation lAnim = new RotateAnimation(0, -45, 250, 50);
        lAnim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        lEditTxt.startAnimation(lAnim);
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 5):

You could try overriding EditText onDraw method like so...

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
     canvas.save();
     canvas.rotate(45.0f,xpivot,ypivot); //rotate around (x,y) pivot point 
     super.onDraw(canvas);
     canvas.restore();
}
```

I haven't tested this, but I think it should work.

Comment: This will do it.  To clarify, you will have to write a custom `RotatedEditText extends EditText` and this + constructors can be the only thing in it.

Comment: I think you will have to do some additional work related to touch events, though. All you are doing is *drawing* the widget rotated.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for your quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

"Custom EditText" means you extend EditText and you override the draw method, drawing the text the way you want it.